# How do I prove that the standard basis in $\mathbb{F}^n$ ($\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$) is orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have seen that people just use the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{F}^n$. In that case I can see clear that the norm of every vector is $1$ and are pairwise orthogonal. But I wonder if I just can assume that specific inner product on $\mathbb{F}^n$ or it can be proven on every general inner product on the vector space just using the  definition of inner product on a general vector space. How do I prove it in general?

Comment: If you think for a minute then you'll see that it cannot possibly be true in general. Try and come up with a bilinear map $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle'$ which satisfies all properties of an inner product but $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ is not an orthogonal set. Try and work with $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ or $\Bbb{F}^{2}$ if it makes life easier for you.

Comment: There are other inner products on $\mathbb R^2$ where these aren't orthonormal, so it is not independent of the inner product. For example, on $\mathbb R^2$ the inner product $(x_1,x_2)\cdot_a(y_1,y_2)=2x_1y_1+x_2y_2$ does not make the standard basis orthonormal.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron
Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
Clear example, thank you!